# Washer creating small holes in clothes

Tags: repair, washing-machine, washer

My new front load washer is creating little holes in my clothes and I am trying to fix the problem but I don't know what to do.

The holes look like little circles about 2mm in diameter and they often come in pairs.

When looking inside the drum, the distance and pattern of the holes seems to match the little metal holes scattered throughout the drum.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Furthermore this is not normal wear and tear as it happens in new high quality clothes as well, and started as soon as I got my new front load washer. It's also not due to buttons or zippers or overloading as it happened in small t-shirt only loads too.

Comment: This seems more like a usage question than a repair question, which would be off topic. This may help: https://www.thespruce.com/holes-in-clothes-after-washing-2146665

Comment: Seems that there's lots of discussion on this topic: https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/796325/help-my-washing-machine-is-putting-holes-in-my-clothes

Comment: "My **new** front load washer is creating little holes in my clothes". Umm, return it? You could also call the company and complain. They will either tell you "that's strange, we'll send out a tech" or "Sorry, we've been getting this a lot, here is a new one"

Comment: does it happen when running a load w/o detergent?

Answer (score 1):

It is of course possible that the drum is damaged or that the laundry is worn down between the rubber and the drum. Most likely, the drum is too full and the laundry is damaged as a result.